# How to replicate viewbox behaviour for label in Xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to rewrite my WPF app to Xamarin.forms but I got stuck at scaling the label to maximum available space.

In WPF I could simply do:

```
<Viewbox Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="3"
         HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Label Width="auto" Height="auto"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
           Content="ABCD"/>
</Viewbox>
```

I tried something like this but it expands only background of label not the text

```
<Label Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="3"
       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
       VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
       Text="ABCD"
/>
```

Does xamarin.forms provide something similar in behaviour to label inside viewbox from WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard Viewbox in Xamarin so the short answer is: no.

I found at least one 3rd party implementation: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/92662/viewbox-implementation-for-xamarin-forms but I cannot vouch for it as I haven't used it.

Answer (score 0):

I've came up with this quite naive solution:

XAML:

```
<BoxView x:Name="measureViewBox"
         Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
         Opacity="0"/>
<Label x:Name="myLabel" 
       Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
       Text="ABCD">
```

Code behind:

```
private void ContentView_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double fontSize = measureViewBox.Width;
    myLabel.FontSize = fontSize;
    SizeRequest measurement = myLabel.Measure(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity);
    while (measurement.Request.Width >= measureViewBox.Width)
    {
        fontSize -= 2;
        myLabel.FontSize = fontSize;
        measurement = myLabel.Measure(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity);
    }
}
```

It's lagging very much when I resize the window in UWP but, at least for now, it gets the job done. I will try to improve this in the future, so any suggestions would be appreciated.